# Make a grouped barplot from count value in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, grouped-bar-chart

Good day everyone, I'm working with a fairly large dataset and am attempting to make a grouped barplot using ggplot2 in R. I'm struggling trying to divide my plot. I want to get the count for each month by the different types of members.

So far this is my code

```
bike_rides %>%  
  group_by(member_casual, month_of_use) %>%  
  summarize(Count = n()) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=month_of_use, y=Count)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill=member_casual, stat="identity", position= "dodge"))
```

This output produces this error:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bksaD.png)

Farily new to R so please be patient with me, any feedback is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I think you have a typo in the geom_bar line, should close the `aes` parenthesis sooner:  `geom_bar(aes(fill=member_casual), stat="identity", position= "dodge")`, since those other bits are parameters you want to send to `geom_bar` and not aesthetic mappings that belong inside `aes()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to answer my question thanks to @Jon Spring, closing the aes sooner made the difference!

```
bike_rides %>%  
  group_by(member_casual, month_of_use) %>%  
  summarize(Count = n()) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=month_of_use, y=Count, fill=member_casual)) + 
  geom_bar(stat='identity', position= "dodge")
```

[New Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yck2t.png)

Practice makes perfect!